# Creating a unique (attribute) title in a Model

Tags: python, django

I have a blog project and users can create posts with similar titles, How can I prevent a user or even the admin from proceeding without getting an error that the title already exists so that I can avoid future errors in the website such as `get() returned more than one Post-it returned 2!`

I have tried to use class meta for unique together but still, post was saved with the same title

Here is the post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
class Meta:
        unique_together = ('title', 'slug')
```

Comment: What exactly should be considered similar? If both field are identical, or only one? And please show us the query producing the error, including the full traceback.

Comment: If the title of a post already exists in database, any users submit a new post  or even the admin should get an error that it already exists. The title should be a unique title and not similar to any previous ones. I am not getting an error now it is saving normally but in the post-details when there are more than one post with the same title I get this error `get() returned more than one Post-it returned 2!` which makes sense as there should be one title per one post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `unique=True`

```
 title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

See the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique).